# Excel: How to write a formula for increment?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on writing a formula for salary increase.

I want to write a formula that would increase the base amount after every 6 months automatically by x amount. Which function should I use for this? Or is there any other way to get this to work out? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Comment: That's simple addition or multiplication. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, simple math. Have a cell with hire date. Use Month() and/or Year() functions to get the time elapsed. Try something and show us what you get if you cannot get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In cell **A1** enter the start date and In cell **B1** enter the starting salary.  In cell **A2** enter below written formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+6,DAY(A1))
```

In **B2** enter this formula:

```
=B1+2500
```

*(or similar formula can be used for the six month increment)*

Then copy downwards:

[image]

This approach allows you to project both the amounts and the increment dates.